# logout using cookies php

Tags: php

This is the way i set cookies for authentication purpose, but i need a logout function to destroy those cookies...and send back to index page, please help me out??

```
<?php
require_once('Template.php');
require_once('common/common.php');

$mes="";
if($value['m']==1)
 {
    $mes="Invalid Username / Password.";
    setcookie("USERNAME", "", time()-3600);
 }

$template =& new Template('html/login.html');
$template->AddParam('mes',$mes);
$template->EchoOutput();

?>
```

actually i forgot to post the login authentication code...

```
<?php
 require_once('class/User.php');
 require_once('common/common.php');
 $user= new User();

 $user->getUser($value['username'],$value['password']);

 if($user->ID != null){
setcookie("USERNAME", $user->USERNAME);
header("Location:adminhome.php");

  }
 else
 {
 header("Location:index.php?m=1");
 }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`logout.php:`

```
setcookie("USERNAME" , '' , time()-50000, '/');
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

add a link to `logout.php`. logout.php should contain the code above.

> setcookie("USERNAME" , '' , time()-50000, '/');

this destroys the cookie.

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

this redirects the user to index.php

I've removed the `if` statement cause i've realised it's not useful here

Comment: i have used ur code and it logged out successfully, but after logout if i press the back button in browser, it again goes back to the insider page.

Comment: Does the insider page check whether a user is logged in? If it does, which cookie is it checking for?

Comment: yes this auth() is written in al the insider page.....


function auth(){
 
 if(!$_COOKIE["USERNAME"]){
  
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
   
  }
 }

Comment: have you tried visiting an 'insider page' afresh without using the back button, as the back button can sometimes show you the cached copy if the page

Comment: if i close the browser, it works fine, even if i dont apply the logout part, as there is my auth(). but on same browser after several refresh the logout isn't working.....

Comment: @dhruba try this for auth `function auth(){ if(!isset($_COOKIE["USERNAME"]))` add the `isset`

Comment: buddy tried a lot, its not working.......i cant understand where is the fault, everything is seems to be right. gosh!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently unsetting the cookie in your example. Also, setting a cookie with no value is the same as deleting it. Then simply redirect to your landing page after logout.

```
setcookie( 'cookie_name'); // deletes the cookie named cookie_name
Header("Location: url.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add an exit(); statement after the call to Header().